# FEDEX API, Authentication Failed

Tags: java, soap, fedex

I am integrating FEDEX Tracking, Rate and Shipping API's into my application but i am stuck with an issue.

When i run my code with Developer account details, everything runs correctly. But when i run the same code with production keys, it gives me **"Error Code 1000, Authentication Error"**

I have updated all keys and also changed the URL to point to production URL "https://ws.fedex.com:443/web-services/".

It doesn't seem to be a permission issue from FEDEX end as the standard services(Tracking) are enabled by default for production and that's also giving the same error **"Error Code 1000, Authentication Error"**.

Below is the SOAP request and response XML.

REQUEST:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header/>
<soap:Body>
<RateRequest xmlns="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v14">
<WebAuthenticationDetail>
<UserCredential>
<Key>AAAAAAAA</Key>
<Password>BBBBBBBBB</Password>
</UserCredential>
</WebAuthenticationDetail>
<ClientDetail>
<AccountNumber>CCCCCCCC</AccountNumber>
<MeterNumber>DDDDDDDD</MeterNumber>
</ClientDetail>
<TransactionDetail>
<CustomerTransactionId>java sample - Rate Request</CustomerTransactionId>
</TransactionDetail>
<Version>
<ServiceId>crs</ServiceId>
<Major>14</Major>
<Intermediate>0</Intermediate>
<Minor>0</Minor>
</Version>
<ReturnTransitAndCommit>true</ReturnTransitAndCommit>
<RequestedShipment>
<ShipTimestamp>2015-04-19T18:21:11.542+05:30</ShipTimestamp>
<DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</DropoffType>
<ServiceType>FEDEX_GROUND</ServiceType>
<PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</PackagingType>
<TotalInsuredValue>
<Currency>USD</Currency>
</TotalInsuredValue>
<Shipper>
<Address>
<StreetLines>1310 Piper Dr</StreetLines>
<City>Milpitas</City>
<StateOrProvinceCode>CA</StateOrProvinceCode>
<PostalCode>95035</PostalCode>
<CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
</Address>
</Shipper>
<Recipient>
<Address>
<StreetLines>3370 E. La Palma Avenue</StreetLines>
<City>Anaheim</City>
<StateOrProvinceCode>CA</StateOrProvinceCode>
<PostalCode>92806</PostalCode>
<CountryCode>US</CountryCode>
<Residential>false</Residential>
</Address>
</Recipient>
<ShippingChargesPayment>
<PaymentType>SENDER</PaymentType>
<Payor>
<ResponsibleParty>
<AccountNumber>ACCOUNT_NUMBER_PRESENT</AccountNumber>
</ResponsibleParty>
</Payor>
</ShippingChargesPayment>
<RateRequestTypes>ACCOUNT</RateRequestTypes>
<PackageCount>1</PackageCount>
<RequestedPackageLineItems>
<GroupPackageCount>1</GroupPackageCount>
<InsuredValue>
<Currency>USD</Currency>
<Amount>100.00</Amount>
</InsuredValue>
<Weight>
<Units>LB</Units>
<Value>10</Value>
</Weight>
<Dimensions>
<Length>1</Length>
<Width>1</Width>
<Height>1</Height>
<Units>IN</Units>
</Dimensions>
<SpecialServicesRequested/>
</RequestedPackageLineItems>
</RequestedShipment>
</RateRequest>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

RESPONSE:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<v14:RateReply xmlns:v14="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v14">
<v14:HighestSeverity>ERROR</v14:HighestSeverity>
<v14:Notifications>
<v14:Severity>ERROR</v14:Severity>
<v14:Source>prof</v14:Source>
<v14:Code>1000</v14:Code>
<v14:Message>Authentication Failed</v14:Message>
</v14:Notifications>
<v14:TransactionDetail>
<v14:CustomerTransactionId>java sample - Rate Request</v14:CustomerTransactionId>
</v14:TransactionDetail>
<v14:Version>
<v14:ServiceId>crs</v14:ServiceId>
<v14:Major>14</v14:Major>
<v14:Intermediate>0</v14:Intermediate>
<v14:Minor>0</v14:Minor>
</v14:Version>
</v14:RateReply>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Please help me resolve this issue :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting the error for all web services in production then you've got a key issue. Get new credentials from the developer area of FedEx or try emailing websupport at fedex.com

Comment: Thanks, the issue was from fedex end. The services were not enabled from their end.

Answer (score 3):

I faced this issue from last week and found solution finally after a discussion with FedEx Technical Person.See why we are facing such error all because of  Developer Test Account we generated from developer website.One thing we should keep in mind that Test Account Number start with "6" is of Production & Key Start with "5" is Correct Test Key.So Please check your Test Key when you get Authentication problem with Error Code 1000.

Revert me if this is not helpful.

Comment: I created a new test credential set, for India. But the account number in it started with 6, whereas for US&Global it started with 5. Regardless of the countries/regions, shouldn't they work the same since they are for test env?

Answer (score 2):

https://www.xadapter.com/test-use-fedex-account-number-test-account-number-password-use/

User Account Password is different from password we have to supply in web service.
please check above link

Answer (score -1):

I struggled and so I called their support in US, which I'll say is excellent. I had a chance to speak to some developer who will observe your requests in real time and will inform you over call like what's causing this authentication issue. Call here >> 1.877.339.2774

Now as per their support person, sometime while registering multiple times the earlier generated password gets overwritten with new, while key / account & meter numbers remain the same. (test & prod key passwords are sent over email you've registered with).

So if you're sure that you're using test/production credentials correctly mentioned in your code then you try re-registering for keys and must put your direct email address on the registration form. The new password will help you get a success response from APIs.

Also, if you're using api to track a shipment, then test creds will only help if you've supplied a test tracking number, same is for production keys. Prod keys will only work for real shipment tracking IDs